# How to convert the text to date format in excel

Tags: excel, date, text, macros

1. How to convert the below text to a date format the current format of
   the text is general if i try convert the text to date by right
   clicking the cell and selecting the format cells iam not able to
   convert.
2. My text is "March 10, 2015 1:05:34 PM GMT+05:30" i want to convert
   this text to date format in excel.
3. The converted text should be in mm/dd/yyyy format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
=DATEVALUE(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A2, " ", REPT(" ", 99)), 299)))+TIMEVALUE(LEFT(RIGHT(A2,21), 12))
```

If you are trying to recover the UTC, then some further parsing of the UTC differential would be necessary.

[image: time_parse]

Comment: I need the converted text should be in mm/dd/yyyy format

Comment: The result of the formula is NOT a text value. It is a real numeric datetime. Format the cell to whatever you want it to look like. As a matter of fact, if the time is not important to be added then you can remove the TIMEVALUE portion of the formula (the second half).