# Excel convert text (April 1, 2017) to date

Tags: excel, vba, date, text, excel-formula

I have some dates in my Excel spreadsheet that are in this format to change it to convert to a date format of `dd/mm/yyyy`, or any form that allows me to sort by date.

How would I be able to do this using a formula? `April 1, 2017 = 01/04/2017`

Thanks!

P.s. I've looked through the question: [How to convert the text to date format in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36011173/how-to-convert-the-text-to-date-format-in-excel)
It looked similar, but the formula doesn't work even when I take out the timevalue portion.

Comment: Are you sure it is not already a date that is formatted that way?    Excel has no problem changing the string you provided to a date for me. Try Text-to-Columns selecting date time on the third step.

Comment: Just as a test, change the format of the cell to General...  does it still say Apr 1, 2017?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but it's seen as text for me. When I go to change format, the short date and long date shoes as "April 1, 2017" which signals to me that Excel is not seeing it as a date but rather as text. When I'm in General, the text is still April 1, 2017 as well.

Comment: @ScottCraner, I've just done the Text-to-Columns, trying delimited and Fixed width. Delimited works better after clicking in and checking comma and space. It seperated it afterwards when I clicked Date on a MDY basis. It didn't turn it into a date format - DD/MM/YY, but that helps tons cause it's at least seperated now :D. Was there anything that I did wrong in those steps btw?

Comment: Do not split. Leave as one column. And just choose mdy on that column

Answer (score 0):

If the "date" is being read as text, and your "date" format will always be mmmm d, yyyy, you can try the following (assuming cell A1 has the "date"):

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),MONTH(LEFT(A1,3)&1),MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,FIND(",",a1)-FIND(" ",A1)-1))
```

After which, you can just set a custom dd/mm/yyyy format to that date. OR you can enclose the formula above in a `TEXT()` function:

```
=TEXT(DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),MONTH(LEFT(A1,3)&1),MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,FIND(",",a1)-FIND(" ",A1)-1)),"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

What I would recommend, however, is using the first formula and setting a custom format.